# delphi 7 fortes report read error RLReport.dcu

Tags: delphi

its a long time since i have used delphi 7 and realy cant find out how to fix thise problem, its been a week and i have no more ideas. Im have to do some updates in an existing project, it uses fortesReport and i get thise error "[fatal error] Unint.pas(7): Read error on '....\FortesReport\RLReport.dcu'"

i have googled, try evething i know i it steel apears, done as it says in the readme.txt, compile and boom! the error again, download fortesReportComunityEdition, install it and again

please i realy dont know what else to do

Comment: Looks like you may need to re-install this library into the IDE.

Comment: Do you have `RLReport.pas`? If so, delete the .dcu and build your application. If you don't, contact the vendor and get a fresh .dcu for your Delphi 7 version (if they can still supply one - Delphi 7 is nearly 15 years old now).

Comment: i dont have the pas, as much i know its free but the component to download have only dcu, it says its for delphi 7 [source page](http://fortesreport.com.br/?page_id=25) but doesent work

Comment: interesting thing is that i delete the component, delete the path in library path and i still get the error saying the path to the component, how does it still know where is supose to be it? where else do i have to delete the things?

[Fatal Error] ReporteX.pas(7): Read error on 'X:\Sistems\Components\FortesReport\RLReport.dcu'

Comment: finally works, day 5 and solve the problem, delete all the packages form component/install package, project/options/package, delete all the references from tools/enviroment options/library/library path and browsing path, project/options/directories/search path, detele all the fortesReport files from C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi7\Projects\Bpl, unzip the fortesReport ce open the frce.dpk compile and install, compile my project and now it runs, thanks for taking your time to answer